# show loading.. image when processing onclick event

Tags: jquery

A button click event triggers filtering on a data table. While JQuery is processing that , the page should display a loading image.This is not an ajax request.

This is my code that doesn't work :

```
$("somebutton").click(function(){
  $("#loader").show();
  // do some stuff.....
  //...
  // now hide the loader again
  $("#loader").hide();
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change your `onclick` to `click`.

Comment: I meant to type click. will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your do some stuff can use a callback function then put the hide loader function in that.
Something like

```
$("somebutton").click(function(){
  $("#loader").show();
  $("yourselector").method(something, function(){$("#loader").hide();});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("somebutton").click(function(){
  $("#loader").show();
  // do some stuff.....
  //...
  // now hide the loader again
  $("#loader").hide();
});
```

Use `click` instead of `onclick`